# Why can I not compile this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I am compiling following algorithm:

```
\begin{algorithm}

\caption{Random Projection}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
    \REQUIRE Paired input ($CP_{n\times s}$), User-specific key ($RP_{s\times s}$)
    \ENSURE  Cancelable template ($CT_{n\times s}$)
    \FOR {$i = 1$ to $n$ in $CP_{n\times s}$}
       \FOR {$j = 1$ to $s$ in $CP_{n\times s}$}
          $CT(i,j)$= $CP(i,j) \times RP(i,j)$ 
       \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR
    \RETURN $CT_{n\times s}$
\end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}
```

I am getting an error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \ENDFOR

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I think it might be, that in your `For` loop a `\STATE` is missing but that depends on the algorithm-environment/package you're using

Comment: I added that with a little explanation as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment suggests, that the OP is using the `algorithm` package. In there, any command line has to be started with a `\STATE` which is missing in his inner `for` loop. So

```
   \FOR {$j = 1$ to $s$ in $CP_{n\times s}$}
      $CT(i,j)$= $CP(i,j) \times RP(i,j)$ 
   \ENDFOR
```

Should read

```
   \FOR {$j = 1$ to $s$ in $CP_{n\times s}$}
      \STATE $CT(i,j)$= $CP(i,j) \times RP(i,j)$ 
   \ENDFOR
```